# Rotating arm mounted on a differential base?

Tags: differential-drive

First time on this forum and I’d like to ask about a project I’d want to do. I’d like to build a robot, preferably on a differential drive base (two driving wheels, one or two caster wheels) and have an arm which can rotate mounted on top. This video provides a concept of what I’m trying to achieve although it has a four wheel skid steer base.

https://youtu.be/iE2HxXjoqeM?t=3

The reason I’m drawn to a differential base is that I’m concerned about loss of directional accuracy through turns if I was using a skid steer application. I also feel that mecanum wheels may not do so well as the robot will be working on asphalt which can be rough and slightly uneven.

To provide some idea of the accuracy I hope to achieve the robot will need to drive straight for almost 20 meters, reverse back to the half way mark the turn 90 degrees and drive a further 15 meters and hopefully be within 50mm of it’s intended path, the more accurate the better though.

I would like to be able to set the robot running and not need to have any input until it has completed it’s path. I would also like to incorporate some simple monitoring channels for a thermocouple which may adjust the travel speed and to be able to trigger a relay.

Is this a reasonable goal for a ROS2 application? At this point in my research the only other option I am aware of, which may not tick all boxes is CASP (Computer Aided Simulation Program).

I see there is a tutorial which may be suitable for this project but there has been some negative feedback citing issues of broken repository references. Planning For Differential-Drive Mobile Base and an Arm tutorial is broken · Issue #364 · https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/issues/364

Any thoughts or suggestions on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The "rotating arm" part of your title doesn't seem relevant to navigating the robot base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ros1 or ros2 have all the features you'll need for this task, but achieving 5cm accuracy using dead-reckoning on uneven pavement is unlikely. For accurate localization, you'll need additional sensor(s), as well as predetermined landmarks you can rely on.